# print a linear linked list into a table

Tags: java, printing, linked-list

I am attempting to print some values i have stored into a LLL into a readable table.
The data i have stored is the following :

```
DEBBIE     STARR           F 3 W 1000.00
JOAN       JACOBUS         F 9 W  925.00
DAVID      RENN            M 3 H    4.75
ALBERT     CAHANA          M 3 H   18.75
DOUGLAS    SHEER           M 5 W  250.00
SHARI      BUCHMAN         F 9 W  325.00
SARA       JONES           F 1 H    7.50
RICKY      MOFSEN          M 6 H   12.50
JEAN       BRENNAN         F 6 H    5.40
JAMIE      MICHAELS        F 8 W  150.00
```

i have stored each firstname, lastname, gender, tenure, payrate, and salary into their own List. And would like to be able to print them out in the same format that they are viewed on the text file i read them in from.  i have messed around with a few methods that allow me to traverse and print the Lists, but i end up with ugly output. . .

here is my code for the storage of the text file and the format i would like to print out:

```
public class Payroll
{
  private LineWriter lw;
  private ObjectList output;
  ListNode input;
  private ObjectList firstname, lastname, gender, tenure, rate, salary;

  public Payroll(LineWriter lw)
  {
      this.lw = lw;
      this.firstname = new ObjectList();
      this.lastname = new ObjectList();
      this.gender = new ObjectList();
      this.tenure = new ObjectList();
      this.rate = new ObjectList();
      this.salary = new ObjectList();
      this.output = new ObjectList();
      this.input = new ListNode();
  } 
   public void readfile()
   {
       File file = new File("payfile.txt");
       try{
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
           while(scanner.hasNextLine())
           {
               String line = scanner.nextLine();
               Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
               lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");
               while(lineScanner.hasNext())
               {
                   firstname.insert1(lineScanner.next());
                   lastname.insert1(lineScanner.next());
                   gender.insert1(lineScanner.next());
                   tenure.insert1(lineScanner.next());
                   rate.insert1(lineScanner.next());
                   salary.insert1(lineScanner.next());
                }
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
    }


   public void printer(LineWriter lw)
   {
       String msg = " FirstName " + " LastName " + " Gender " + " Tenure " +
                    " Pay Rate " + " Salary "; 
             output.insert1(msg);
             System.out.println(output.getFirst());
             System.out.println(" " + firstname.getFirst() + "      " + lastname.getFirst() + "\t" + gender.getFirst() +
            "\t" + tenure.getFirst() + "\t" + rate.getFirst() + "\t" + salary.getFirst());


     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`System.out.printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method for printing the strings and integers into fixed-width places (with alignment) using [C-style format specifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this

```
 String msg = " FirstName " + " LastName \t" + " Gender \t" + " Tenure \t" +
                " Pay Rate \t" + " Salary \t";
```

Comment: the string msg isnt the problem. the problem is the output of the list.  It happens either 1234556789 or

Comment: 1
2
3
4... and i need it to be organized in the table is all